# Android : SQLiteException: not an error not on all devices

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I get this error on a device, while it works good on another device. Here is the error :

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.nativeFillWindow(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
    at com.Orange.MakeVisits.Themes.onCreate(Themes.java:162)
```

I execute a query and at the line that checks if the Cursor is null, I get this error. Here is my code :

```
    String stmtGetThemes = "SELECT * FROM pr_fields_descriptor a "
   + "inner join pr_fields_starring b on a.id_fields_descriptor = b.fields_descriptor_id "
   + "where b.starring_id = '"+pos_starring_id+"' and a.theme_id='"+themes_ids[m]+"' order by form_rank";

    Cursor getThemesCursor1 = db.databaseQuery(stmtGetThemes);

    if (getThemesCursor1!=null && getThemesCursor1.getCount()>0){
    //----
    }
```

and databasequery is this method (is defined in the class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`):

```
public Cursor databaseQuery(String stmt) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(stmt, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Any idea what can cause this error ? The statement is not good ? Why it works on others devices?
Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advace.

Comment: If `pos_starring_id` and `themes_ids[m]` are integers, you should remove the quote (`'`) marks around them from the query so they are not treated as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Pass array Type Paramters in Query, sometimes it won't work

```
int themes_id = themes_ids[m];

String stmtGetThemes = "SELECT * FROM pr_fields_descriptor a inner join pr_fields_starring b on a.id_fields_descriptor = b.fields_descriptor_id where b.starring_id = '"+pos_starring_id+"' AND a.theme_id = '"+themes_id+"' ORDER BY form_rank";

Cursor getThemesCursor1 = db.databaseQuery(stmtGetThemes);

if (getThemesCursor1 != null && getThemesCursor1.getCount() != 0){
//----
}
```

Comment: I changed like you said, but it still crashes.

Comment: check the whitespace is used properly

Comment: I don't see any whitespace that could make it crash.

Comment: "form_rank" what is it ? Is it a database column or a variable name

Comment: Now Check my answer completely, it will help

Comment: Then you don't have bug in a query,you have bug in UI. Because Closely look at the error  at com.Orange.MakeVisits.Themes.onCreate(Themes.java:162)

Comment: this is the line 162: if (getThemesCursor1!=null && getThemesCursor1.getCount()>0){

Comment: Change to : if (getThemesCursor1 != null && getThemesCursor1.getCount() != 0){

Comment: it still crash at that line :( I saw that in entire application I get this error where I check if the cursor is null, but sometimes is just a warning. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: remove that getThemesCursor1.getCount() !=0

Answer (score 0):

```
String stmtGetThemes = "SELECT * FROM pr_fields_descriptor a "
   + "inner join pr_fields_starring b on a.id_fields_descriptor = b.fields_descriptor_id "
   + "where b.starring_id = '"+pos_starring_id+"' and a.theme_id='"+themes_ids[m]+"' order by form_rank";
```

Do not terminate this query by ";".